# leader lines in FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I have a pie chart in Dynamics CRM that has the values of the segments listed outside of the pie chart.  However I am trying to get the leader lines to display from the chart to the values. What property am I missing?   Here is the XML.

```
 <Series>
    <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Outside, LabelsHorizontalLineSize=1, LabelsRadialLineSize=1, PieDrawingStyle=SoftEdge" ChartType="doughnut">
      <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
    </Series>
  </Series>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the lines were not showing up was because the attribute PieLineColor was not set to a color